# How to merge two dictionaries and setting new key values to 0?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, for-loop, combinations, dictionary-comprehension

I have two Python dictionaries, and I want to write a single expression that returns these two dictionaries, merged. I need to have to following input and output

Let's say we compare two sentences
"I like potatoes" and
"I like tomatoes"

input

```
dict1= {"I": 1, "like":1,"potatoes":1}
dict2= {"I": 1, "like":1,"tomatoes":1}
```

To compare them we need them in the following output

```
dict1 ={"I": 1, "like":1,"potatoes":1,"tomatoes":0}
dict2 ={"I": 1, "like":1,"potatoes":0,"tomatoes":1}
```

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Is order actually relevant? Would ``{"I": 1, "like":1,"tomatoes":1,"potatoes":0}`` be okay as well?

Comment: The order of the two new dictionaries should be the same @MisterMiyagi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (python 3.9+ for `|` dictionary merge operator) :

```
dict1 = {"I": 1, "like": 1, "potatoes": 1}
dict2 = {"I": 1, "like": 1, "tomatoes": 1}

union = dict1 | dict2

res1 = {k: dict1.get(k, 0) for k in union}
res2 = {k: dict2.get(k, 0) for k in union}

print(res1)
print(res2)
```

output :

```
{'I': 1, 'like': 1, 'potatoes': 1, 'tomatoes': 0}
{'I': 1, 'like': 1, 'potatoes': 0, 'tomatoes': 1}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
In [14]: dict1= {"I": 1, "like":1,"potatoes":1}
    ...: dict2= {"I": 1, "like":1,"tomatoes":1}

In [15]: keys1 = dict1.keys()  # dict keys are set-like: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict-views

In [16]: keys2 = dict2.keys()  # get keys of dict2 in another set()

In [17]: dict1.update(dict.fromkeys(keys2 - keys1, 0))  # to build result from the items in dict1 and the "keys in dict2 but not in dict1" with value 0

In [18]: dict1
Out[18]: {'I': 1, 'like': 1, 'potatoes': 1, 'tomatoes': 0}

In [19]: dict2.update(dict.fromkeys(keys1 - keys2, 0))  # same here

In [20]: dict2
Out[20]: {'I': 1, 'like': 1, 'tomatoes': 1, 'potatoes': 0}
```

Comment: Note that ``dict.keys`` are already set-like; there is no need to convert them to sets explicitly. For example, ``dict1.update(dict.fromkeys(dict2.keys() - dict1.keys(), 0))`` works out of the box.

Comment: The order of the key-value pairs in you answer doesn't match to the OP's requested output.

Comment: why would anyone care about the order of a dict without using an [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) ?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi that's right, the dict keys are already hashed sets

Comment: @ibigbug since python 3.6, dictionaries are ordered (insertion order)

Comment: @SorousHBakhtiary thank you good to know: https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2017-December/151283.html

This makes me started questioning 


`Explicit is better than implicit.  # who expects a "hashmap" that has ordered keys`

and 
`Simple is better than complex.  # purpose of OrderedDict is to let people know that a dict is just a dict, not an "OrderedDict"
`

but anyways :)